# Clonezilla Backup: Zeroing out unused space APFS SSD

Tags: clonezilla

Context: MacOS Big Sur APFS SSD.

Is there a command to zero out unused SSD space and verify that the unused space is zeroed?  I ask because many times files are not erased when they are deleted: they are backed up with Clonezilla and make the back file larger than necessary.

The goal is to minimize the size of the backup

Comment: When Clonezilla recognizes the file system and can use Partclone, it will only copy used data blocks. This means that unused space will not occupy space in the backup. But when Partclone is not used, Clonezilla falls back on dd, and unused space should be zeroed. So first check if Clonezilla can use Partclone (for example ext4, NTFS, FAT32), and if necessary consider how the zeroize the unusued space.

Comment: For ext4 you can use `zerofree`, otherwise you have to rely on `dd`, let it write a huge file with binary zeroes until it can no longer write, and then remove the file. If you fill the system partition of the running operating system, you may get serious problems, so you had better do it from another system, for example booted from an external drive (if you have an external operating system that can work with APFS).

Answer (score 1):

In order for `clonezilla` to backup just the used space, [it needs](https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/support-requests/98/?page=1) `partclone` to support the filesystem. That support has been added recently, but it is still considered experimental.

Download the testing version of `clonezilla` (right now at 3.0.2...) and you can test it out. Note however that the Clonezilla forum states:

> Of course, since it's the initial [APFS] support, please backup important data before you use.
> Please give it a try and let us know the results if you can.

Comment: +1 Thanks for these current details :-)